# Voltage Controlled Voltage Source Circuit Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, source

I don't know what I'm missing with the analysis of this question. Obviously I know that there's no voltage through the 105k resistor. I know that the current from the VCCS is given by the input voltage times the gain factor.

However, I would have assumed that, based on this, the current from the VCVS would have been 1.003 * 10mS = 0.001003. Ltspice tells me that the current generated is 4.8mA. I can't see where this is coming from. I've probable just stared at it so long that I've over complicated it to all hell. Any help is appreciated :)

Ltspice circuit and dc op values found here:

[image]

EDIT: Typed VCVS by accident!

Comment: Isn't that a VCCS, rather than a VCVS?

Comment: Also, as a VSCS, it takes the voltage difference across its terminals, the positive side, surely sees 1.003 with respect to the ground you have defined. But the lower terminal also sees a finite voltage, which is the current of the VCCS, times the resistor R3. Therefore, the current of the VCCS is a function of the current flows through it. If you build the equations that way, does it simulation result make sense?

Comment: Thank you so much! Really should just go to bed now haha!

Comment: Explain 'no voltage through the 105k resistor'

Answer (score 1):

> the current from the VCVS[sic] would have been 1.003 * 10mS = 0.001003.

Why do you say that?

The voltage being sensed by the VCCS is the voltage from source V1, minus the voltage across R3.

If you want the output of the VCCS to be \$1.003 \times 10\ {\rm mS}\$, you should connect the negative terminal of the sense input of the VCCS to ground, not to the node between the VCCS output and R3.

FWIW, I hand-calculated the result based on the circuit you presented, and I also got 4.8 mA for the VCCS output current.